# Neo4j: How Can I display the row position?

Tags: neo4j, return, cypher, row

I have a label Person with properties:name and birthDay, how can I display a new field with the position?

[image]

I would something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a temporary collection :

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH collect(p) AS persons
UNWIND range(1, size(persons)) AS i
RETURN i AS pos, (persons[i-1]).name AS name, (persons[i-1]).birthDay AS birthday

╒═════╤══════╤════════════╕
│"pos"│"name"│"birthday"  │
╞═════╪══════╪════════════╡
│1    │"Raf" │"05/07/1992"│
├─────┼──────┼────────────┤
│2    │"Mary"│"10/08/1991"│
├─────┼──────┼────────────┤
│3    │"Luke"│"11/01/1995"│
└─────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a solution with a more simple return?

Comment: There isn't, there is nothing that holds a position except the neo4j internal id but this will not be starting with 0 and be incremental

Comment: In addiction considering the id you could have duplicated or incorrect ids :/